# Collapse id with new value depending on another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
id <- c(rep(1, 5),rep(2,6))
fico <- c(rep(700,5), rep(600,6))
time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6)
default <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
e<- data.frame(id, fico, time, default)
e
  id fico time default
1   1  700    1       0
2   1  700    2       0
3   1  700    3       0
4   1  700    4       0
5   1  700    5       0
6   2  600    1       0
7   2  600    2       0
8   2  600    3       0
9   2  600    4       1
10  2  600    5       1
11  2  600    6       1
```

And I would like to transform it to something like this :

```
  id2 fico time2
1   1  700     5
2   2  600     4
```

Working with survival analysis, the idea is, for each id, to look at the default column. If there is a 1, the value of time 2 will be, for this id, the minimum value of time for which there is a 1. If there is only 0 in the default column, then the time2 for this id will be the maximum value of time.

I think it might be possible with group_by and mutate but I'm not good enough to do it at the moment.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: All `default` for `id==1` are 0, so why you have 5 in `time2`?

Comment: Because it is the maximum value of `time` for `id==1`

Comment: Are there id with only `1` in 'default'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
e %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 summarise(time2 = ifelse(all(default == 0), max(time), time[which.max(default == 1)]),
           fico = fico[time2])

     id time2  fico
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     1     5   700
2     2     4   600
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative from `dplyr` package. This approach cannot be generalized, but works specifically for your question.

```
e1 <- e %>% 
    filter(default == 1) %>% 
    mutate(time2 = min(time)) %>% 
    filter(time == time2) %>% 
    select(id, fico, time2)

e2 <- e %>% 
    filter(default == 0) %>% 
    mutate(time2 = max(time)) %>% 
    filter(time == time2) %>% 
    select(id, fico, time2)

e <- bind_rows(e1, e2)
e

#id fico time2
# 2  600     4
# 1  700     5
```